# Pass the Group-Object property to further output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I pass the `Group-Object` property to further output?

With this PowerShell command

```
 $log | Group-Object -Property Date | % { $PSItem.Group | measure -Property Sent,Receive -Sum }
```

I got

```
Count    : 37269
Average  :
Sum      : 732408700
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Sent

Count    : 37269
Average  :
Sum      : 212846968
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Receive

Count    : 27813
Average  :
Sum      : 553072764
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Sent

Count    : 27813
Average  :
Sum      : 162171286
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Receive
```

but I want to know to which group these values belong.

Comment: PowerShell version is 4.0, but if there is a different handling in newer version, please tell me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$PSItem has your GroupInfo object.  Just access the `Name` property on it:

```
$log | Group-Object -Property Date | % { $PSItem.Name; $PSItem.Group | measure -Property Sent,Receive -Sum }
```